# Resources on Mathematica and strong AI (a.k.a. AGI)

Tags: simulation, reference-request, expression-construction

David Deutsch (physicist / quantum computing theorist) wrote an article for *Aeon Magazine* last year: [On Artificial Intelligence](http://www.aeonmagazine.com/being-human/david-deutsch-artificial-intelligence/) that got me thinking.

The article assesses and critiques the achievements in AI and articulates criteria one needs to meet to realize [strong AI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_AI) or what he calls Artificial General Intelligence (AGI).

Some key ideas from the article:

- *What is needed is nothing less than a breakthrough in philosophy, a
  new epistemological theory that explains how brains create
  explanatory knowledge and hence defines, in principle, without ever
  running them as programs, which algorithms possess that functionality
  and which do not.*
- *...the ability to produce new explanations.*
- *...brain in a vat*.
- *Because genuine knowledge, though by definition it does contain truth, almost always contains error as well.*
- *...it is simply not true that knowledge comes from extrapolating repeated observations.  Nor is it true that ‘the future is like the past’, in any sense that one could detect in advance without already knowing the explanation.*

The article inspired a number of discussions among my colleagues.  We see a thread of rather obscure work across the entire history of information theory that looks like it addresses many of Deutsch's concerns.

We use this stuff in a variety of sequential decision problems.

**Mathematica and AGI**

So naturally the question came up:

> *Can we model AGI in Mathematica?*

This is a broad question, however, so below the question will be narrowed down. But first, here are some reasons why I think *Mathematica* may be suitable for this purpose.

A lot of work in AGI gets programmed in Lisp and other [homoiconic](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DefinitionOfHomoiconic) and/or functional languages. Homoiconic languages internally represent code and data in the same way.  This could provide a program the capability to modify itself, perhaps even to evolve or adapt to a new problem.

*Mathematica* sees everything as an expression.  It has the ability to generate functions.

Wolfram Alpha certainly has some kind of AI calculation/search underpinning it, but I don't see it as attempting AGI.

**The question is**: Can anyone direct me to:

> - *examples of Mathematica used in work on AGI*;
> - *individuals using Mathematica for work on AGI*;
> - *resources about using Mathematica for work on AGI*;

Also, if anyone has an interest in thinking through this in greater detail, just ping me (email in my profile) and I'll forward more background information on our ideas.

Comment: Very interesting stuff, but too broad, I fear.

Comment: @YvesKlett -- Why too broad?  Examples exist or not, individuals doing it exist or not, resources about it exist or not.  Participants here may or may not know of any of these, but why would that make the question too broad?  I have asked about the feasibility on Mma for a specific branch of AI and only for R&D and modeling.  These seem like quite specific inquiries.  We have tags for questions about using Mma in physics and chemistry.    If such questions would stand in those areas, why not AI?

Comment: @Artes - Reference-request tag added.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I concur with your skepticism.  My interest goes more to ease of use and general feasibility.  AGI might most easily get accomplished with some language paradigm no one has yet to conceive.  Until such a time, maybe Mma could help nudge some ideas forward.

Comment: from what i've gleaned offhandedly, it seems Lisp was used back then because people thought intelligence had something to do with logic... which is, of course, hilariously naive. Lisp being an expression language and having cultural roots in mathematics made it a good choice for logic programming. there's a chapter in one of Paul Graham's books (free online i believe) that builds a Prolog interpreter in Lisp after implementing continuations, if i recall correctly. statistical machine learning and neural networks are the closest we've come so far to "general" AI, and these are language-agnostic

Comment: @amr -- From his article, Deutsch would refute that statistical machine learning and neural networks as well as anything following induction or Bayseian methods could come anywhere close to AGI.  Worth the read;-)

Comment: @Jagra i did peruse the article. i'll give it a serious read later, but one thing i will mention is that your brain plays an enormous number of tricks on itself. eg it's entirely possible that "consciousness" is not only an illusion, but one that is deliberately perpetrated and sustained by the brain itself. i also think the issue of creativity is much easier than it sounds, and has mainly to do with the kind of memory an individual has (eg different people are creative in different ways because they store memories in different ways). don't be too certain about anything involving intelligence!

Comment: This is clearly too broad. What is even a definition of AGI versus AI? The linked article is quite rambling and seems a little vacuous to me, certainly doesn't help me in defining what is being asked.

Comment: Have you posted it on Wolfram Community?

Comment: I think we haven't seen enough questions about AI on MMA.SE yet. It makes sense that a discussion will then be quite broad. I appreciate the term AGI. AI is such a broad field and many of the algorithms there can solve interesting problems, but also clearly have a limited scope and can never be used to make a "human like intelligence". I think Mathematica is excellent for this sort of stuff. So +1 from me. Definition of [AGI and strong AI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_AI).

Comment: I liked the AGI definition, but as the articles says, nobody knows how to to something like that today! Maybe @MrWizard can surprise us (Or maybe he is an AGI?? Oh my god!:)

Comment: @Murta Agree with the first part (read only the first paragraph in Wikipedia and knew I can stop right there), but if Mr. Wizard were AGI he wouldn't need *Mathematica*, would he? Or is he implemented in *Mathematica* -- version 7??

Comment: I honestly don't understand how anyone considers this question too broad.  I've provided a link to a definition of strong AI and asked for specific kinds of references to: examples, individuals using MMa for it; and resources about using MMa.  I did ask additionally for thoughts on feasibility. All of these constitute requests for information about using MMa for a specific thing.  Whether anyone has achieved it or not doesn't matter.  Whether anyone has answers doesn't really matter.  Can anyone explain why they believe the question too broad?

Comment: Jagra and other users, I hope I have narrowed the question down sufficiently. In my opinion it can be reopened.

Comment: As far as anyone knows, computational expressiveness of Mathematica is suitable to make "AGI" work. So is computational expressiveness of stack-machine assembly language or "traditional" Turing machine model with an infinite tape.

What is needed to reach "AGI" is the intellectual and conceptual breakthrough. I believe Mathematica, in this regard, can't offer much in taking that giant leap. Surely it's in practice an easier environment than tape-based Turing machine, but nonetheless it's "only" a programming environment - and not actually that different from others.

Comment: I agree with @kirma, the question "Can we model AGI in Mathematica?" for me is the same as "Can we model AGI in a Turing Machine?". My modest opinion is that we really don't know. We do not understand if consciousness is necessary in this kind computational process, and we don't know if we have all the necessary laws of physics to understand consciousness. So, I agree that the question is too broad to our humble Mathematica forum.

Comment: @Murta - I appreciate all the concerns you and kirma raise, but I haven't asked the question, "Can we model AGI in Mathematica?" of this forum.  Ive asked for references.  I don't hold any particular hope that this specific community can solve AGI.  I supplied an article that lays out the challenges in conceptualizing either intelligence or AGI quite clearly.  I do hope to find or identify other work and workers in the area (if they exist) that use Mathematica.  This seems like an appropriate kind of question for this forum.

Comment: Ok. Just to mention, the paper is very interesting. I really like this topic.

Comment: Just my humble opinion: from the perspective of an outsider to this field, the question comes across like "can we do bioinformatics/density functional theory/quantum chromodynamics in *Mathematica*?". Even if you know exactly what you mean, I think that, lacking a specific problem as an example, even specifying a sub-sub-subfield of study is still not concrete enough for almost any reader to know how to respond. I don't VTC since I think it's fair enough for you to ask whether there are others working in this field and, if so, what they are doing. But, I think an answer is very unlikely.